# Use MVT to prove $(1+x)^{k}\leq 1+k x$

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem:

> \begin{array}{l}{\text { Use the mean value theorem to prove the following. }} \\ {\text { If } k \text { is a positive real number and } x \geq 0, \text { then }(1+x)^{k} \leq 1+k x,} \\ {\text { provided } 0<k \leq 1}\end{array}

I know that the mean value theorem states:

$$f'(c)(b-a)=f(b)-f(a)$$

Now, I assume I have to find the right function which I can use the MVT for. But, I am not able to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=(1+x)^k$$
you have $$f'(x)=k(1+x)^{k-1}$$

Using the MVT, we have that there exists $c$  such as $0 <c< x$ and

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(c)x$$

$f'$ is decreasing because $0 < k \leq1$, therefore $$f'(c)\leq f'(0)=k$$

Finally,

$$f(x) \leq 1+kx$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you got $k$ into the picture in this step: $$f'(c)\leq f'(0)=k$$

Comment: $0<c$ therefore $f'(c)<f'(0)$ because $f'$ is decreasing, we have $$f'(0)=k(1+0)^{k-1}=k$$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the pre-edited version of the question:

The statement is false. For  example $(1+n)^{2} \leq 1+kn$ is not true for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: My apologies. I've made a mistake in typing the question it must be $(1+x)^k$ and not $$(1+x)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\gt0$, we have

$${(1+x)^k-1\over x}={f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}=f'(c)$$

for some $c\in(0,x)$, where $f(x)=(1+x)^k$.  Now $f'(c)=k(1+c)^{k-1}\le k$, since $0\lt k\le1$ (and $c\gt0$).  Thus

$${(1+x)^k-1\over x}\le k$$

if $x\gt0$, hence $(1+x)^k\le1+kx$ for $x\gt0$. Finally, we have $(1+x)^k=1+kx$ for $x=0$ (both sides equal $1$), so the inequality holds for all $x\ge0$.

Remark: We get from ${(1+x)^k-1\over x}\le k$ to $(1+x)^k-1\le kx$ (and from there to $(1+x)^k\le1+kx$) by multiplying both sides of the initial inequality by the *positive* quantity $x$.  When moving multiplicative factors around in inequalities, it's always important to check the sign of what you're moving around. Neglecting to do so can result in serious errors (as I have learned, repeatedly, from experience).